# About the $6N$ dimension when describing the Boltzmann equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-space

I have a question related with the formulation of the Boltzmann equation. In all the documents I read, it appears that the system is made of $N$ molecules, and so the phase space has $6N$ dimensions (in 3D). But later, all the treatment is with a $6$ dimension space. Why is the space reduced from $6N$ to $6$? In one of the descriptions, I found that in fact, the distribution $f(r,p,t)$ is the integration over all particles except one. Is this related to non-distinguibility of particles? Any physical clue on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...*Is this related to non-distinguibility of particles?*..."

Yes. But it is more subtle than that. We can integrate the full probability distribution function (for $N$ particles) , $f_N(x_1, p_1 ; x_2 , p_2 ; ... x_N , p_N ; t)$ over the variables $x_i, p_i$ for $i = 2...N$ , to generate the $1$ particle distribution $f_1 (x_1, p_1, t)$, because we are dealing with $N$ non-distinguishable particles .

*Why* we would be interested in $f_1$ is a different matter. What we are trying to generate, ultimately, are hydrodynamic equations for macroscopically conserved quantities (in the most simple case, mass/number , energy and momentum). All of these can be expressed as moments of $f_1$. Number density $N(x,t)$ = $\int_p f_1(x,p,t)$, energy density $E(x,t) = \int_p \frac{p^2}{2m} f_1(x,p,t)$ etc.

So, from the point of view of understanding macroscopic non-equilibrium phenomena, knowledge of $f_1$ is enough. This is why we want an equation for just $f_1$ (the Boltzmann equation).

Note that just because we would *like* an equation for $f_1$ doesn't mean that we can always write one down. The Liouville equation obeyed by the full distribution $f_N$ is equivalent to a *chain* of integro-differential equations, relating $f_1$ to $f_2$, $f_2$ to $f_3$ etc. This chain is called the *BBGKY hierarchy*. We can only write down the *Boltzmann equation* (an equation for $f_1$ that involves *only* $f_1$) , if we can truncate this chain after the first equation , by assuming that $f_2(1,2) \approx f_1(1) f_1(2)$. In other words, writing down the Boltzmann equation requires us to assume that motions of particles participating in "collisions" are *uncorrelated* before and after the collisions (basically, at any time except *during* the collisions) (also known as the assumption of "Molecular Chaos")

For example, see chapter $2$ of David Tong's notes on Kinetic theory (https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/kinetic.html), or $\S$16, *Physical Kinetics*, Lifshitz and Pitaevskii

Comment: Thank you very much. It was something I wasn't sure how to answer and that I couldn't see very well explained...

Comment: Just one thing more: a point in the phase-space is a microsystem of the system. Thus, a point there is not a "particle". In this sense, N(x,t) would be the number of microstates that will define the same macrostate for a given system of N particles, right? So with $f_1$ what you have is a microsystem where you only look at one particle property because the rest of them will be as this one, since are indistinguisible. no? Then when you break the BBGKY is because you let 2 particle interaction, and say that for any microsystem, the collision of 2 particles is not correlated.

Comment: $N(x,t)$ is the density. Literally, number per unit volume. $f_1(p,x,t)$ is the 1-particle probability distribution function. If we are talking of PDF's, we are already one step ahead of counting "microstates". If we had an isolated, constrained system, then, as you say, each allowed point in (full 6N dim) phase space is a "microstate" ; $S = ln \Omega$ , where $\Omega$ is the total # of allowed microstates given the constraints. Compare this with the case where you are given a PDF $\rho$. In this case, $S = -\sum    \rho ln \rho$. As you can see, we no longer refer to "microstates" any more

Comment: If you want to think of a chain (microstates $\to$ PDF $\to$ macrostate), Here, the *densities* ($E(x,t)$ , $N(x,t)$ etc) constitute the description of the "macrostate". Remember that we are trying to describe a situation which is macroscopically out of equilibrium. That is what hydrodynamics is. Macroscopic equations for out of equilibrium.